# Can I make Code Runner extension on VSCode work with ES6?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules

I’m learning js modules and am running into the following issue:

When I use
`module.exports = MessageMixer` and `const MessageMixer = require("./messageMixer")` everything works fine.

However, if I try to use export default like so: `export default MessageMixer` and then `import MessageMixer from "./messageMixer"` I get a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error when I run my code with the **Code Runner extension on VSCode**.

I did a bit of searching and it looks like this has to do with ES6 support.

Is there any way to make Code Runner work with ES6 instead of having to transpile my code from ES6 to ES5 with Babel every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

The key is configuring the `code-runner.executorMap` for JavaScript in your VSCode settings, so that Code Runner uses Babel's (ES6-transpiling) Node instead, like this:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "$workspaceRoot/node_modules/@babel/node/bin/babel-node.js $fullFileName"
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/29).